# 'How to fix 'JQuery Dropdown inside dropdown''

Tags: jquery, html, dropdown, dropdownbox, cascadingdropdown

I'm setting up my resume in my website using multiple dropdowns

I have tried youtube tutorials and css/jQuery

```
<div0 class="dropdown">
    <button class="button"><img src="resume start.PNG" alt="resume" width="auto" height="auto"></button>
    <div00 style="display:none;" id="dropcontent">
    <img src="resume detail.PNG" alt="detail" width="auto" height="auto">
        <div000>
            <button class="button1"><img src="career goal-objective.png" alt="career goal/objective" width="auto" height="auto"></button>
                <div0000 style="display:none;" id="dropdown">
                    <img src="job goal.png" alt="job goal" width="auto" height="auto">
                </div0000>
        </div000>
    </div00>
</div0>




$(document).ready(function(){
  $("div0").click(function(){
    $("div00").toggle();
     });
});
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("div000").click(function(){
    $("div0000").toggle();
     });
});
```

I expect the dropdown to act as a normal dropdown, but it actually opens the dropdown then the other closes the dropdown. But when it opens again, it has the second dropdown open

Comment: Please create a [mcve] of your problem

Comment: Can you please point to an online documentation that speaks about this HTML tags `<div000>` ?

Comment: After using valid html tags fix having two document ready declarations, you should have only one.

Answer (score -2):

You need to check if the div is visible or not inside the jquery...the toggle put the visibility on, but nothing put the visibility off...like this, give it a try

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("div0").click(function(){

  if($("div0000").is(":visible")) {
        $("div0000").toggle();
  }

    $("div00").toggle();
     });
});
    $(document).ready(function(){
  $("div000").click(function(){

    if($("div00").is(":visible")) {
        $("div00").toggle();
    }

    $("div0000").toggle();
     });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div0 class="dropdown">
    <button class="button"><img src="resume start.PNG" alt="resume" width="auto" height="auto"></button>
    <div00 style="display:none;" id="dropcontent">
    <img src="resume detail.PNG" alt="detail" width="auto" height="auto">
        <div000>
            <button class="button1"><img src="career goal-objective.png" alt="career goal/objective" width="auto" height="auto"></button>
                <div0000 style="display:none;" id="dropdown">
                    <img src="job goal.png" alt="job goal" width="auto" height="auto">
                </div0000>
        </div000>
    </div00>
</div0>
```

Comment: Please, be fluent with HTML and JS. Answers should be helpful, not a prolongation of serious issues.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I edited my answer, but seriously, the only thing to do was to copy and paste what i wrote in his jquery...that was not a prolungation of an issue, a copy-paste was the only thing needed and i specified why...but ok...

Comment: Alesssz Why do you use DOM ready twice? What kind of tag is `<div000000>` ? Why there's no suggestion about not using spaces in filenames? Why there's no suggestion about DRY principles? Why don't you show a small and reusable function that does what a copy paste does? Why there's no suggestion about not using inline insecure style attributes? Why you didn't used the `type="button"`? Please Alesssz..., if you see a man trying to catch a fish with a needle, giving him three more needles is nice, but not helpful. If you don't understand how fishing works, perhaps you know a friend who can help?